# What do I need to add to my AndroidManifest to be able to send Whatsapp messages on the latest Sdk?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I am writing a MAUI app for a small group of users, and this code used to work. We were able to generate whatsapp messages to send a code to new clients. But now we can't send whatsapp messages anymore.

The call to `Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync()` returns false, even though we have whatsapp on the phone.

The minSdkVersion is 29 and the targetSdkVersion is 33.

```
public static class WhatsApp
{
    public static async Task<bool> SendAsync(string phoneNumber, string message)
    {
        if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("0"))
            phoneNumber = "27" + phoneNumber.Substring(1);
        else if (phoneNumber.StartsWith("+"))
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.Substring(1);

        var supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync($"whatsapp://send?phone=+{phoneNumber}");
        if (supportsUri)
        {
            await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync($"whatsapp://send?phone=+{phoneNumber}&text={message}");
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to my AndroidManifest.xml for this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After android 11 you have to add this line in manifeast

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
    <queries>
        //for normal whatsapp
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
        //for business whatsapp
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b"/>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```